# json decode changing the value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have below json array.

```
{"entries":[{"uid":155551338258538,"photo":"https:\/\/m.ak.fbcdn.net\/profile.ak\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/323887_155551338258538_1152153357_q.jpg","type":"user","text":"shikhadamodar","path":"\/shikha.damodar.1","category":"Madiun","names":["shikhadamodar"],"index_rank":-1,"needs_update":true,"non_title_tokens":"madiun"},{"uid":155551332173428,"photo":"https:\/\/m.ak.fbcdn.net\/profile.ak\/hprofile-ak-snc3\/273318_155551332173428_2131571532_q.jpg","type":"user","text":"shreya damodar","path":"\/my.devprofile","category":"Nilai","names":["shreyadamodar"],"index_rank":-1,"needs_update":true,"non_title_tokens":"nilai"},{"uid":155555587232111,"photo":"https:\/\/m.ak.fbcdn.net\/profile.ak\/hprofile-ak-prn1\/41332_155555587232111_3158_q.jpg","type":"user","text":"neha neha","path": "\/neha.neha34","category":"New York, New York","names":["Neha neha"],"index_rank":-1,"needs_update":true,"non_title_tokens":"new york, new york"}],"token":"1333551453-7","display_token":5,"display_ttl":1333541132}
```

when i decode this json array, i am getting ,

```
array(4){["entries"]=>array(3){[0]=>array(10){["uid"]=>float(1.5555133825854E+14)["photo"]=>string(90) "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-prn1/323887_155551338258538_1152153357_q.jpg"["type"]=>string(4) "user"["text"]=>string(13) "shikhadamodar"["path"]=>string(17) "/shikha.damodar.1"["category"]=>string(6) "Madiun"["names"]=>array(1){[0]=>string(13) "shikhadamodar"}["index_rank"]=>int(-1)["needs_update"]=>bool(true)["non_title_tokens"]=>string(6) "madiun"}[1]=>array(10){["uid"]=>float(1.5555133217343E+14)["photo"]=>string(90) "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-snc3/273318_155551332173428_2131571532_q.jpg"["type"]=>string(4) "user"["text"]=>string(14) "shreya damodar"["path"]=>string(14) "/my.devprofile"["category"]=>string(5) "Nilai"["names"]=>array(1){[0]=>string(13) "shreyadamodar"}["index_rank"]=>int(-1)["needs_update"]=>bool(true)["non_title_tokens"]=>string(5) "nilai"}[2]=>array(10){["uid"]=>float(1.5555558723211E+14)["photo"]=>string(83) "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-prn1/41332_155555587232111_3158_q.jpg"["type"]=>string(4) "user"["text"]=>string(9) "neha neha"["path"]=>string(12) "/neha.neha34"["category"]=>string(18) "New York,New York"["names"]=>array(1){[0]=>string(9) "Neha neha"}["index_rank"]=>int(-1)["needs_update"]=>bool(true)["non_title_tokens"]=>string(18) "new york,new york"}}["token"]=>string(12) "1333551453-7"["display_token"]=>int(5)["display_ttl"]=>int(1333541132)}
```

first UID in json is  `"uid":155551338258538,`

when it comes to array, it becomes `["uid"]=>float(1.5555133825854E+14)`

why is it so??

After getting `1.5555133825854E+14` a a reult, ho can i change that to real UID `155551338258538`
?

Hope some great coder can help on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling big user IDs returned by FQL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/handling-big-user-ids-returned-by-fql-in-php)

Comment: can you please write php code which you are using to decode the json because its working fine for me.

Comment: Yeah this can't really be solved without code. Decimal point is clearly being moved. Are you casting it as a double or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution of your problem the UID string is long intger hence json_decode is converting it to scientific notation. Try this

```
print_r(json_decode($arr, false,512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

Comment: its working... but .. i gonna lose the game. its getting more and more complicated each day.. @chandresh_cool

Comment: @sheryadamodar what happen any problem again?

Comment: hem... i cant get it to work yar. 

have you seen the app i try to make? 
https://apps.facebook.com/friendrequests/


I cant chat because i have no reputation, where can i talk instead of in comment?? @chandresh_cool

Comment: Well I have not worked on it but definetly can u help you to come out of it. Tell me what is the problem now? after u added the above code

Comment: it throws an error. 
Warning:json_decode() expects at most 3 parameters,4 given in -- on line 634 @chandresh_cool

Comment: I think this is your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508946/trouble-using-function-json-decode

Comment: yaa.. i understood.. thanks dear.. i wasted much time on this. :/

Comment: Okay @sheryadamodar not a problem. May be upgrading the version will be helpful as I am running 5.4 version of PHP and am able to decode it properly. Any help let me know.